# How to do complex calculations inside query formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

In Google sheets, I get #NA with no explanation when I try to calculate the change between two sums - that I have just calculated in that same formula.

Is that not possible using query or am I doing it wrong?

- My formula: `=query(B5:H16,"select ((sum(G)/sum(F)) - (sum(D)/sum(C))) / (sum(D)/sum(C))")`

The first part is working: `=query(B5:H16,"select ((sum(G)/sum(F)) - (sum(D)/sum(C)))`

I'm trying to do the same calculation as the formula in A3 in the screenshot - but within the query formula

Spreadsheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VrYO-TayV6TD-iHUDT3Axgkr3gI4s9OHvj0-yW59wRA/edit#gid=0

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet with formulas and data]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Done! Good point :)

Comment: any reason why query is needed for this?

Comment: Yes. In the real data I fetch data from many columns onto one row. So if I can handle all the calculations within just one formula per row it'll make everything easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this be equivalent to the formula you are trying to get?:

```
=query(B5:H16, "select (sum(G)/sum(F))/(sum(D)/sum(C)) - 1")
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thank you. It works great in the example sheet. But when I add this part (sum(K)/sum(J))/(sum(H)/sum(G))-1 in front of the where clause in a longer formula, it doesn't work anymore - but return #NA. Like this: query('sheet'!A:Z,"select sum(A),sum(B),'1',sum(B)/sum(A),'all c',F,sum(G),sum(H),sum(H)/sum(G),sum(J),sum(K),sum(K)/sum(J),(sum(J)-sum(G))/sum(G),(sum(K)-sum(H))/sum(H),(sum(K)/sum(J))/(sum(H)/sum(G))-1 where F matches '"&join("|",'sheet'!F5:F15)&"' group by F")

Comment: @Sigurd, you're welcome. In this case I'd suggest you to create a new question explaining what you want to accomplish, since this was not part of the original question.